# How to store the value of telnet->cmd in an attribute in perl script

Tags: perl, grep

I have been running

```
grep -n \"fixed-address $IP_Address\" /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf | cut -d \":\" -f2"
```

inside `telnet->cmd` and I want to store the output in a variable. I got an output value of `1` when I tried, but the output value should be 916. Here is a part of my Perl script

```perl
my $dhcp_value = $telnet->cmd(
    string => "grep -n \"fixed-address $IP_Address\" /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf | cut -d \":\" -f2"
);

print "$dhcp_value\n";
```

Please let me know how to run `grep -n` command in `$telnet->cmd`

Comment: Per the documentation, `In a scalar context, the characters read from the remote side are discarded and 1 is returned on success` are you sure you don't need `@dhcp_value` instead of `$dhcp_value`?

Comment: I tried to use @dhcp_value to store value, but it didn't work in my case. Below is an output which i have seen if i define array variable to store value                 Output-The value of dhcp is admin1@dhcp9-desktop:~

Comment: Have you specified prompt in the constructor?

Comment: Yes i have defined a prompt in the constructor like below. $telnet = new Net::Telnet (Prompt => '/\$ $/i');

Comment: Post the output of  `input_log() or dump_log()`

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add these details. There's an [edit] link below the question's tags.

Comment: Are you using `Net::Telnet`?

Comment: *"I tried to use @dhcp_value to store value, but it didn't work in my case"* It is very difficult to be clear about code or data within comments. You have a huge advantage in having a *question* that you can edit and use to provide properly-formatted information, please use it! I would like to see exactly why using an array didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [`Net::Telnet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet) module, then the documentation for the `cmd` method says this

> In a scalar context, the characters read from the remote side are discarded and 1 is returned on success
>
> In a list context, just the output generated by the command is returned, one line per element.

So it looks like you need to apply *list context* to the `cmd` method call. You can either use an array, like the example in the documnentation, or you can just put your scalar variable in parentheses

What I think you need is this

Note that I have built the command stringf separately for clarity, and used alternative delimiters with `qq{...}` so as to avoid having to escape embedded double quotes

Note also that the return value from the `cmd` call will probably have newline characters at the end. `chomp` will remove these for you

```
my $cmd = qq{grep -n "fixed-address $IP_Address" /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf | cut -d ":" -f2};

my ($dhcp_value) = $telnet->cmd(string => $cmd );
chomp $dhcp_value;

print "$dhcp_value\n";
```